# Set Graphqlobjectype

Tags: graphql

This is my JSON response from a GET request:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: {rendered: 'Project 1'},
  content: {rendered: 'Lorem ipsum'}
},
{

  id: 2,
  title: {rendered: 'Project 2'},
  content: {rendered: 'Lorem ipsum'}
},
{

  id: 3,
  title: {rendered: 'Project 3'},
  content: {rendered: 'Lorem ipsum'}

}]
```

This is how I create my GraphQL object:

```
const ProjectsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'ProjectItem',
    description: 'This object is a project',
    fields: () => ({
        title: {
            description: 'Le titre du projet',
            type: StringType
        },
        content: {
            description: 'Le contenu html du projet',
            type: StringType 
        },

    }),
});
```

How can I access my second objects title and content? I know I have to do a resolve but I don't understand how.

Comment: The names of your GraphQL object's fields are the same as the property names in your JSON data. So, you don't need resolve function for the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
fields: () => ({
  title: {
    description: 'Le titre du projet',
    type: StringType,
    resolve: (root) => root.title.rendered
  },
  content: {
    description: 'Le contenu html du projet',
    type: StringType,
    resolve: (root) => root.content.rendered
  },
}),
```

Comment: Thank you very much